# Snapping to segments not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, snapping, vertices, segment

QGIS 3.x does not let me snap to vertice and segment anymore, only vertices.

I changed the snapping options several times in the toolbar and in the options menu. Made sure the correct layers are activated. Restartet everything.

I even uninstalled QGIS 3.4 deleted all app data and installed 3.10 instead but the problem prevails.

I can not bring QGIS to snap to segment or follow an existing shape.

Does anyone have a solution?

---

I am familiar with the settings and choosing the right ones is unfortunately not the problem. Also zooming closer, or starting a new layer did not help. Neither did importing the layers into a new project.

Using standard CRS WGS84

---

I am familiar with the settings and choosing the right ones is unfortunately not the problem.
Also zooming closer, or starting a new layer did not help.
Neither did importing the layers into a new project.

Using standard CRS WGS84

Comment: Please support your issue with some images. it is an uncommon problem that is difficult to replicate.

Answer (score 8):

To get the snap to vertices to work make sure you have the following options selected:

- Enable Snapping (U magnet button)
- Enable topological editing
- Enable snapping on intersection
- Enable tracing
- Make sure the projection for both layers are the same

I've provided a snapshot of the options to select below - this works on 3.4 and 3.10.

[image: Snap Options]